# Nesting of shortcode in Wordpress (simple)

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have looked before posting, but I have only seen more complex use cases which I don't understand.

My scenario is pretty simple...

I have 2 shortcodes which are just text.

The first one is a phone number:

```
// Add Shortcode
function calltracking1_shortcode() {
return '800-555-1234';
}
add_shortcode( 'phone_1', 'calltracking1_shortcode' );
```

The second one I want to have the `phone_1` shortcode be called and show within it:

```
// Add Shortcode
function company_nap_shortcode() {
return '
ABC Company Name, Inc<br>
12345 Street Address<br>
City, ST 12345<br>
Phone: [phone_1] <br>
Individual ID: 1234567';
}
add_shortcode( 'company_nap', 'company_nap_shortcode' );
```

This works on another site I have, but not one I'm working on.

How would I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to run the content of your second shortcode function through [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

So, it would probably be the easiest to write your second function like this:

```php
function company_nap_shortcode() {
  return do_shortcode('
    ABC Company Name, Inc<br>
    12345 Street Address<br>
    City, ST 12345<br>
    Phone: [phone_1] <br>
    Individual ID: 1234567');
}
```